# Create a new email template header

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I want to create a different header template for sales emails i.e. `header sales instead of the default header`. The template files are defined in `locale/LANG/template/email/html/` simply creating a new template file `headersales.html` and referencing it in the new order email template as

```
  {{template config_path="design/email/headersales"}}
```

Doesn't work. Are the template names defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Paj,this should not work.

For this case you need to create handler  and this handler will render the you phtml at local.xml at `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PAackage/YOUR_template/layout`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <amit_customer_addhan>
        <block type="core/template" name="reviewreminder.email.items" template="Folderlocation/headersales.phtml" />
    </amit_customer_addhan>
</layout>
```

then on email **html call this handler(locale/LANG/template/email/)**

```
 {{layout handle="amit_customer_addhan" order=$order}}
```